# iid mean 0 random variables, $E{|S_n|}=o(n)$?

Tags: probability

Let $X_i$ iid mean 0 random variables without finite second-moment assumption. Let $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$. Then, I want to prove $E{|S_n|}=o(n)$, i.e., $E\left(\dfrac{|S_n|}{n}\right)\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

I have no finite second-moment assumption.

I'm trying to use SLLN and uniform integrability: By SLLN, $\dfrac{|S_n|}{n}\rightarrow 0$ almost surely. Then, as $X_i$'s have finite mean, so do $|X_i|$'s and let this value $c$.
$$\sup_nE\left(\dfrac{|S_n|}{n}\right)\leq \sup_nE\left(\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n|X_i|}{n}\right)=c<\infty$$
Further, for any $\epsilon>0$,
$$\sup_nE\left(\dfrac{|S_n|}{n}I_A\right)\leq\sup_nE\left(\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n|X_i|}{n}I_A\right)\leq\sup_n\sum_{i=1}^n\left[E\left(\dfrac{|X_i|}{n}I_{A,|X_i|\leq M}\right)+E\left(\dfrac{|X_i|}{n}I_{A,|X_i|>M}\right)\right]\leq...$$
I have not done this way (actually stuck here). Is there any efficient way to prove this?

---

My updated proof (I think this is enough.)

By SLLN, $\dfrac{S_n}{n}\rightarrow 0$ almost surely. Thus, $\dfrac{|S_n|}{n}\rightarrow 0$ in probability.

Note that $\dfrac{|S_n|}{n}\leq \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n|X_i|}{n}$. But since $E\left( \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n|X_i|}{n} \right)=E(|X_1|)=c$ finite, i.e. $\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n|X_i|}{n}$ converges in mean to some constant. Thus $\left\{\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n|X_i|}{n}\right\}$ is uniformly integrable, and so is $\left\{\dfrac{|S_n|}{n}\right\}$.

Hence, $\left\{\dfrac{|S_n|}{n}\right\}$ converges in mean to 0 as desired.

Comment: What you are trying to prove is not true. The Cauchy distribution provides a counter example.

Comment: @GordonSmyth But the Cauchy distribution does not have mean 0?

Comment: Ah, yes, I overlooked that point. The Cauchy has median 0 but the mean is undefined. You are restricting to distributions that have finite means.